# What does health actually mean?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

The health rating on the character select screen, what is the actual meaning for it? The wiki mentions how one health is equal to one red heart container, but this is not the case.

Case in point being Eve which has 1 health but 2 containers.

What does it actually mean?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it maps with some exceptions(?) to just their number of hearts minus 1. It's really more of a reference point telling you what their health is relative to the other characters. But, if you want to know about all the characters specifically (minor spoilers?):

> Maggy: ....4 hearts
>  Isaac: ......3 hearts
>  Cain: .......2 hearts
>  Eve: ........2 hearts
>  Samson:..1 heart,  1 soul heart
>  Judas:......1 heart
>  ???: ........0 hearts, 3 soul hearts